# access denied to folder, even though using admin account

Tags: windows-7, permissions

I have installed Avira anti-virus, but now i cannot open it, access its folder or even remove it.
Each time i try to access its folder i get "access denied" even though im logged in as an admin account.
Even tried accessing it through CMD (with run as admin) but still getting access denied.
I don't even have the right to view the security tab of the avira folder, neither i can view the permission or the owner of the folder.

How can i fix this?

Comment: I suggest to boot through a Linux distro (eg [Knoppix](http://www.knopper.net/knoppix/index-en.html)) and try to open the folder if nothing works.

Comment: Try to access it in safe mode and if it does not work uninstall the Avira. Many anti-virus/malware software mark their services as critical so that viruses cannot disable the antivirus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, how did that happen?

Sounds like you need to take ownership of the files. To forcibly and recursively do this for your Avira directory, open an elevated command prompt and type:

```
takeown /f "c:\path\to\avira" /r
```

Then if you're still having issues accessing the files, reset the permissions with:

```
icacls "c:\path\to\avira" /reset /T
```

Then I'd blow away anything Avira related and reinstall.